# how to include aliases in zsh autocomplete?

Tags: zsh

Folks,

I use a set of aliases and it is annoying to have zsh ask me if I have misspelt it and offering me suggesting me alternatives.

I read some earlier posts about git autocomplete, but what I am looking for is a generic autocomplete of any alias referenced from .zshrc.

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Use `nocorrect` to instruct zsh not to correct a given alias:

```
alias foobar="nocorrect foobar"
```

Source: [ZSH Gem #4: Spell checking and auto correction](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/39/ZSH-Gem-4-Spell-checking-and-auto-correction/)

Comment: or just disable the whole autocorrect thing with `unsetopt correct_all`. I find it's more trouble than it's worth